# How to compare two DB tables of different number of rows based on one attribute in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, comparison, row, html-table

**What I have:**

1.I have two DB tables `display` and `bid`  as listed below:

```
mysql> select * from display where gp_no = 1;

+-------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+
| gp_no | no_of_member | amount    | current_instalment | starting_date | member_no | member_name    |
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |         1 | Akansha Gupta  |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |         2 | Akash Bansal   |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |         3 | Ashish Gupta   |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |         4 | Chavi Jain     |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |         5 | Dhruv Goel     |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |         6 | Mukul Gupta    |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |         7 | Nancy Aggarwal |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |         9 | Prateek Jain   |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |        11 | Rajender Gupta |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |        12 | S K Goel       |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |        13 | Sadhna Goel    |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |        15 | Sandeep Jain   |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |        16 | Sunil Jain     |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |        17 | Sunil Sharma   |
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |        19 | Sunita Gupta   |
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select date , member_no from bid where gp_no = 1 order by member_no asc;
+------------+-----------+
| date       | member_no |
+------------+-----------+
| 2015-06-01 |         7 |
| 2015-05-01 |        16 |
+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**What I want :**

1. I want to compare the `member_no` from both the tables and where I get a match It should display date from table `bid` else it should display **Not Withdraw**. With the code I'm using , I'm able to display only first date i.e., only first match . I probably knows that its because of the mismatch in the no. of rows of both the tables.

[image: This is what I'm getting]

But it should also display the date in front of the `member_no = 16`.

**PHP Code**

```
$sql = "select * from display where gp_no = '$gp_no' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$s_no = 1 ; 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{


 $s = " select date,member_no  from bid where gp_no = '$gp_no ' order by member_no asc"; 
 $r = mysqli_query($conn, $s);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0)
  {
    ?> <h1>Welcome !!! Details of GROUP NO : <?php echo $gp_no ;  ?></h1> 
     <table  align = center ; style="width:50%">
     <tr><th><?php echo " Group Number ";?> </th><td><?php echo $gp_no ; ?></td></tr>
     <tr><th><?php echo " Number of Members ";?> </th><td><?php echo $no_of_member ; ?></td></tr>
     <tr><th><?php echo " Amount ";?> </th><td><?php echo $amount ; ?></td></tr>
     <tr><th><?php echo " Starting Date ";?> </th><td><?php echo $starting_date ; ?></td></tr>
     <tr><th><?php echo " Current Instalment ";?> </th><td><?php echo $current_instalment ; ?></td></tr>
     </table>
     <table  align = center ; style="width:50%" id = " display">
    <tr><th><?php echo "  Sr. Number ";  ?> </th><th><?php echo "  Member Number ";  ?> </th><th><?php echo "  Member Name ";  ?> </th><th><?php echo "  Bid Withdraw ";  ?> </th></tr>
   <?php
   /*$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   $row1_count = mysqli_num_rows($r);
   $remaining_rows = max($row_count, $row1_count);
   while($remaining_rows-- > 0)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r); */
     while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
     {
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 


      ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $s_no ; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $row["member_no"] ; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $row["member_name"] ; ?></td>
    <?php
     if($row["member_no"] === $row1["member_no"])
    {
    ?>
       <td><?php echo $row1["date"] ; ?></td>
    <?php 
     }
    else
     { ?> 
       <td><?php echo " Not withdrawn "; ?></td> 
       <?php } ?> 
   </tr> 
  <?php
       $s_no = $s_no + 1;
        }
        } 
        ?>
  </table>  
      <?php 
        }
            } 
    else
    {
    ?> <h1>  Members not associated yet. </h1> <?php
    }
   }
  mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Comment: You could use joins here.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava : How to do that? I mean I have tried left , inner join suggested by Mak , but it didn't work the way I want it to be. Can you please suggest a layout?

Comment: try the query which i have posted in answer. that should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query it should work as per your requirement

```
SELECT d.member_no, d.member_name, IFNULL(b.date, 'NOT WITHDRAWN')
FROM display d LEFT JOIN bid b ON d.member_no = b.member_no
and b.gp_no='1' where d.gp_no='1'
```

Comment: Yes, it is working but not exactly the same. It is displaying all the records , but I want to filter them where `gp_no = 1` .

Comment: you just have to add a where condition i:e where d.gp_no='1'. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thumbs up Buddy for that. Thanks mate :)  A little last issue is that it is displaying the matched rows twice. How to resolve that?

Comment: I dint get u buddy.Please specify

Comment: You can use a group by condition to avoid multiple records

Comment: Actually it is not displaying the records twice but it is fetching all the dates from `bid` but I want `date` of `gp_no = 1` only . i.e., against `member_no = 7` and `member_no = 16`.

Comment: I've tried it earlier. It was displaying records of only `member_no = 7 and 16` .

Comment: You can now try the query and i think it should be perfect this time :)

Comment: check the updated one -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dab80/1 .  It is fetching all the records even of other groups as well like `gp_no = 2 and 3 ` etc( see the last two rows which gets added when I added two more rows in display table) .Which I don't want . Did you get what I'm trying to say or should I elaborate ?

Comment: Yes i got it. Check the updated query now and see if it works :)

Comment: Thanks a zillion . Finally it worked the way I want .. :)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use OUTER JOIN, Something Like this

```
SELECT d.member_no, b.date
FROM display d LEFT JOIN bid b ON d.member_no = b.member_no
WHERE d.gp_no = 1 AND b.gp_no = 1
```

Comment: If u use inner join then only matching entries in both the tables will be displayed.

Comment: Use Left Join then, If you want all the data from display & the matching ones from bid.

Comment: This is what I'm getting using your query :

<br>      `mysql> SELECT d.member_no, b.date FROM display d INNER JOIN bid b ON d.member_no = b.member_no WHERE d.gp_no = 1 AND b.gp_no = 1  ;
+-----------+------------+
| member_no | date       |
+-----------+------------+
|        16 | 2015-05-01 |
|         7 | 2015-06-01 |
+-----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`  @MaK

Comment: Left join is also displaying the same O/P . and this not something that I'm desiring . I want everything from `display` and only `date` from bid . Now where I get a match of `d.member_no = b.member_no` where d and b are `display`  and `bid`  respectively, I want a date to be displayed the from `bid` else it should display **Not withdraw** . @MaK

Comment: Thanks aton Mate  @Mak :)

Comment: @MaK Please read out the conversation between me and Gautam and suggest a solution. Since Gautam's Query is same as that of yours , I'm getting a problem in that which I have posted at the bottom of my Question. Please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT d.member_no,d.member_name,CASE WHEN b.date IS NULL THEN 'Not Withdraw' ELSE b.date END AS bidDate FROM display AS d LEFT JOIN bid AS b ON d.member_no=b.member_no WHERE d.gp_no=1
```

Comment: I'm getting the same problem as in Gautam's Query .It is fetching all the dates from bid but I want date of gp_no = 1 only . i.e., against member_no = 7 and member_no = 16.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT d.member_no,d.member_name,CASE WHEN b.date IS NULL THEN 'Not Withdraw' ELSE b.date END AS bidDate 
FROM display AS d 
LEFT JOIN bid AS b ON d.member_no=b.member_no AND d.starting_date = b.date
WHERE d.gp_no=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but it isn't working the way I want it to be. The `d.starting_date` is same for all the records in the table`display` for all the members associated with one group lets say `gp_no = 1` . So , it isn't giving the desired results. I can't add a picture to the comment otherwise I'd have shown you the results.